# problem publishing tf map->base_link

Tags: localization, navigation, odometry, mapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I wrote my own localization and I figured out hat amcl is publishing map->odom and not map->base_link.
Which is strange but on the end I had to do the same by computing first the difference to publish map->odom->base_link.
Can anyone help my out to clarify this situation.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188002/problem-publishing-tf-map-%3Ebase_link/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
How did you managed to have map->odom->base_link ? I'm struggling to have map->odom (I already have odom->base_link)

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-07-29**:
Yes my stuff is working.
I had a look how it is done in amcl_node.cpp line 1125-1160.

**Comment by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on 2018-02-08**:
Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Here is a link to the AMCL code with updated line #: http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/amcl/html/amcl__node_8cpp_source.html#l01356

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2018-09-06**:
Hi lalten!
To not edit AMCL, what it does makes perfect sense, have a look at the figures on the bottom of http://wiki.ros.org/amcl and on domhege answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is unintuitively strange indeed, but correct. The reason for that is that TF can only form a tree, thus having /map->/base_link and /odom->/base_link there would be a node with two parents.

More details are here: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-07-29**:
Thanks, now a day later it is clear. It also solves the problem of different update rates and allows a native localization base on the last localization update and odom values.